# POSTing data using for-each with javascript and php?

Tags: php, javascript

foreach loop only repeating the last element of the arary?

**java Script Code :**

```
 <?php foreach($_REQUEST["itemprice"] as $itemprice)
    {
        ?>
        + "&itemname_price[]=<?php echo $itemname?>_price=" + <?=$itemname?>_price.value
         <?php
    }
    ?>
```

**Code to request that data**

```
    $items_price = array();
    foreach($_REQUEST['itemname_price'] as $itemname_pric) {
              $items_price[]=$itemname_pric;
     }
     print_r($items_price);
```

Comment: actually can you please explain what are you trying to do here?

Comment: Did you know you can edit your question? problum, throu, thesnippet, arry? Heard of first letter caps?

Comment: @Dasun
i'm wanted to post that data to the other page so that i can save it in the mysql

Answer (score 0):

foreach is used to get the values from an array, and what you are trying here is to get data from a specific array key. I guess that's why you are getting a single value. You can refer to 
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php to get the exact use of foreach.

Let me know if you have anything to know.